# Using ViewPager with Custom ViewGroups

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewgroup

I'm creating an Android app and I have several custom ViewGroups I've created and wanted to add a ViewPager to my MainActivity so that I can swipe the screen to go back and forth between the Views. However it looks like items added to a ViewPager have to be a Fragment. Do I need to create a separate Fragment for each custom ViewGroup or is there someway to directly add them instead?

Comment: you don't need Fragments at all,  see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for your help. I started out using valbertos solution but my app crashed because I tried to access _idLayout before it was set. I ended up finding this solution

http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using

and modified it to fit my needs and it worked great! Thank you both for your suggestions;

Answer (score 0):

No, you dont need it.

In your FragmenAdapter set a desired id layout for each Fragment, based on the current Position.

//FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
public class DynamicViewsFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public DynamicViewsFragmentAdapter(FragmentActivity activity) {
    super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    DynamicViewsFragment fragment = new DynamicViewsFragment();
    int idLayout = getIdLayoutBasedOnPosition(position);
    fragment.setIdLayout(idLayout);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

private int getIdLayoutBasedOnPosition(int position) {
    if(position == 0) return R.layout.one;
    else if (position == 1) return R.layout.one;
    else return R.layout.three;
}
}
```

//Fragment

```
public class DynamicViewsFragment extends Fragment {

private int _idLayout;

public void setIdLayout(int idLayout) {
    _idLayout = idLayout;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(_idLayout, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

}
```